# Need event handler in another class

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have a user control(VCtrlDetails in the code below) that hosts a data grid(detailsGrid) which is private.
Now, i have this control loaded in another user control(UcResult_Details) and i want to handle grid selection changed event in this another user control.

```
    public partial class VCtrlDetails : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler<bool> EnableEditTemplateButton;
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
             private System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid detailsGrid;
             this.detailsGrid.SelectionChanged += new 
               System.EventHandler(this.detailsGrid_SelectionChanged);
        
         }
        private void detailsGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnableEditButton?.Invoke(this, IsApproved());
        }  
        public bool IsApproved()
        {  }
   }

public partial class UcResult_Details : UserControl
{
    private readonly VCtrlDetails vCtrlDetails;
    
    UcResult_Details()
    {
         //Need to subscribe to vCtrlDetails' grid selection changed event here in this ctor
    }      

}
```

I'm not that well versed with event handlers, so stuck with the solution as the grid object is private in the user control 'VCtrlDetails', so cannot directly do something like:
vCtrlDetails.detailsGrid.SelectionChanged += DetailsGrid_SelectionChanged

Comment: In this case you're not re-surfacing the Grid SelectionChanged event beyond the class that contains it. What your code is doing is raising the `EnableEditButton` (or `EnableEditTemplateButton` - can't tell if that was a typo or there's something else you didn't show) event. Do you want to handle your own event in the `UcResult_Details` class? As it is, you won't be able to handle the `SelectionChanged` event for the grid.

Comment: EnableEditTemplateButton is the event for its own class i.e. VCtrlDetails. I want to handle selection changed event in the class UcResult_Details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bubble the event up and out of the `VCtrlDetails` class. You could do so by creating an event within the VCtrlDetails class and allowing your UcResult_Details class to subscribe to it.

```
public partial class VCtrlDetails : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<bool> EnableEditTemplateButton;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DetailsGridSelectionChanged;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
         private System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid detailsGrid;
         this.detailsGrid.SelectionChanged += new 
             System.EventHandler(this.detailsGrid_SelectionChanged);
        
    }

    private void detailsGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnableEditButton?.Invoke(this, IsApproved());

        //Raise your custom event
        DetailsGridSelectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }  

    public bool IsApproved()
    {
    }
}

public partial class UcResult_Details : UserControl
{
    private readonly VCtrlDetails vCtrlDetails;
    
    UcResult_Details()
    {
         //Need to subscribe to vCtrlDetails' grid selection changed event here in this ctor
         this.vCtrlDetails.DetailsGridSelectionChanged += new 
             EventHandler(this.vCtrlDetailsSelectionChanged);
    }

    private void vCtrlDetailsSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```